# javascript percentages issue

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to calculate the following formula to return a numerical value from 0 - 100 (a grade) depending on the input from a user,

Grade = Exam Worth × Exam Score + (100% − Exam Worth) × Current Grade

and am using the following code to do so,

```
    var total = ExamWorth * ExamScore + (100 - ExamWorth) * CurGrade;
```

Where my 3 variables are just being pulled in from html like so,

```
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="aimGrade">
```

However when I try and calculate I am always getting incorrect answers that I believe have to do not being sure how to convert this to a decimal.

For example an input of ExamWorth = 50 ExamScore = 80 and curGrade = 70 should return a value of 90. Where as i am getting a return of 7500 with the same input.

Comment: Can you give some examples of input and well as what you are getting and what you expect to get?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your issue isn't converting to a decimal (7500 isn't going to become 90 when you divide by 100). Your algorithm is just wrong.**

See algorithm description in the comments.

Also (FYI), there are two things to remember when working with values coming from user-supplied data:

1. All values extracted from HTML will be strings.
2. The order of operations in your algorithm might cause string
   concatenation instead of mathematical addition.

So, here's an example (click to expand the snippet):

```js
var worth = document.getElementById("worth");
var score = document.getElementById("score");
var grade = document.getElementById("grade");
document.getElementById("calc").addEventListener("click", function(){

  // There are a number (no pun intended) of ways to convert strings to numbers
  var worthVal = parseInt(worth.value, 10);  // explicit
  var scoreVal = +score.value;               // coercion
  var gradeVal = Number(grade.value)         // function
  
  // Algorithm:
  var examPer = (scoreVal / 100) * worthVal;   // % of exam worth achieved
  var gradeAvg = gradeVal + examPer / 2;       // average of grades
  
  // Order of operations: Parenthesis, Exponents, Multiplication, Division, Addition, Subtraction
  // Because of the string, any operand on either side of it will normally be converted to a string
  
  // If we were to try to do all the math at once, we have to be very careful about order of operations
  console.log("Result 1: " + (gradeVal + ((scoreVal / 100) * worthVal) / 2));
  
  // But, if we do the math in steps and just put the result with the message, it's much simpler
  console.log("Result 2: " + gradeAvg);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="worth" placeholder="exam worth" value="50">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="score" placeholder="score" value="80">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="grade" placeholder="grade" value="70">
<input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calc">
```

**UPDATE:**

After some thought on this, I don't think the calculation should return `90` as you say you expected. I think it should return `75`. Here's why:

You are providing us with the `Exam Worth` and using that in your calculations, but the only reason you would need that is to get a score (in points), for example:

```
Exam is weighted at 50 
You got 80 percent correct
.8 x 50 = 40 (You got a score of 40 and a percent of 80)
```

But, to get the overall grade, we don't care about the fact that you got a score of 40 on the exam. We only care about the fact that you got 80%, so the `Exam Weight` is irrelevant.

To get the correct overall grade, all we need to do is add the two grades (70 and 80) and divide by 2 (75).

So, in that case, the code would be:

```js
var worth = document.getElementById("worth");
var score = document.getElementById("score");
var grade = document.getElementById("grade");

document.getElementById("calc").addEventListener("click", function(){

  var scoreVal = +score.value;
  var gradeVal = Number(grade.value)
  
  // Algorithm:
  var gradeAvg = (scoreVal + gradeVal) / 2;  // average of grades
  
  // But, if we do the math in steps and just put the result with the message, it's much simpler
  console.log("Result 2: " + gradeAvg);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="worth" placeholder="exam worth" value="50">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="score" placeholder="score" value="80">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="grade" placeholder="grade" value="70">
<input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calc">
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Clears things up and got it working! Much appreciated

Comment: @jelidens But, I was thinking about this. I don't think the answer should be 90. It should be 75. The `ExamWorth` is not needed at all because you're giving us the grade. The only reason `ExamWorth` would be useful is determining your score on the exam (.8 * 50 = 40). We don't need the score if you've already given us the score as a percent  (80 + 70 = 150 and 150 / 2 = 75).

Comment: maybe to clear up some confusion. The idea is to model something like, https://rogerhub.com/final-grade-calculator/

Comment: @jelidens Yeah, just as I thought. If you plug in 70, 75 and 50 in that calculator, it spits out 80%. That calculator calculates a number that you are already supplying in your post here. If we already have that 80%, we don't need the 50 that gets us that number, we only need the 80. The correct answer should be 75, not 90.

Comment: @jelidens In other words, that calculator solves for the percent grade you need to get on an exam if you want a **known final grade**, but your calculator here is trying to solve for a final grade based on a **known exam grade**. The two do different things. Yours is simpler.

Comment: This simple averaging approach only works for a final exam weight of 50%. If you take the same example, but the final exam has a weight of 20%, then the final score would be 72 instead of 75. OP's equation was fine except for a factor of 100.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are mixing up 100% and 100.

If `ExamWorth` is a value between `0` and `1`, you should use `1 - ExamWorth` instead of `100 - ExamWorth`.

```
var total = ExamWorth * ExamScore + (1 - ExamWorth) * CurGrade;
```

If `ExamWorth` is a value between `0` and `100`, then you need to divide by `100`.

```
var total = (ExamWorth * ExamScore + (100 - ExamWorth) * CurGrade) / 100;
```

Using the example you gave, you'd get `75` (instead of `7500`), which is the correct number for calculating the final grade.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could make your inputs numbers:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="aimGrade" min="0" max="100" />
```

which, as you can see, also allows you to do fancy things like add min and max values.

Then you will still have to use the javascript parseFloat() function:

```
var fExamWorth = parseFloat(ExamWorth);
```

Lastly, you may need to revisit your calculation. If your ExamWorth is a value out of 100 (i.e. a percentage), you will need to divide the final result by 100:

```
var total = (ExamWorth * ExamScore + (100 - ExamWorth) * CurGrade) / 100;
```

If it is really a decimal/proportion (i.e. a value between 0 and 1) then it should read:

```
var total = ExamWorth * ExamScore + (1 - ExamWorth) * CurGrade;
```

Comment: Even with `input type=number` the extracted `value` will still be a `string`. The "T" in HTML stands for text, there is no other data format in HTML.

Comment: Indeed. I think I've been too long in the angular universe where the value would be a number!